# How to use foreign key to add data to my database in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, postgresql

I'm using React to send data to my PostgreSQL database using NodeJS. I have a foreign key (id) in my songs as well as my image that references to the album id for my title, date, and description. I'm using a uuid for my id in my album table. My question is how does my songs and image file table know that it was that album id on that page that was created with the songs and image?

Here's the page with the album(title, description, date) which gets saved its own table, the list of songs which gets saved in its own table and the image which gets saved in its own table. Both image and songs table have a album_id which references to the album's id:
[image]

**Album**

```
const addAlbum = (request, response) => {
  const { title, date, description, id } = request.body;
  const uuid = uuidv4();

for (let i = 0; i < request.body.length; i++) {
  db.pool.query('INSERT INTO albums (title, date, description, id) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING RETURNING *' , [request.body[i].title, request.body[i].date, request.body[i].description, uuid], (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error
    } else {
      console.log('INSERT ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
    }
  })
}
}
```

**Songs**

```
 const upsertSong = (request, response) => {
    const { id } = request.body;
    const uuid = uuidv4();
    for (var i = 0; i < request.body.length; i++) {
    let insertQuery = {};
    const object = request.body[i];
    let params = [uuid, object.name, object.link, object.index, object.album_id];
    insertQuery.text = 'INSERT INTO songs (id, name, link, index, album_id) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING *';
    insertQuery.values = params;

    (async () => {

       await pool.query ('UPDATE songs SET name = $1, link = $2, index = $3, album_id = $4 WHERE id = $5 AND index = $3',
        [request.body[i].name, request.body[i].link, request.body[i].index, request.body[i].album_id, id], (err, result) => {
          try {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (result.rowCount > 0){
               console.log ('UPDATE Rows affected: ', result.rowCount);
               return;
             } else {
               pool.query(insertQuery, (error, res) =>{
               try {
                 if (error) throw error;
                 console.log ('INSERT Rows affected:', res.rowCount);
               }catch(er){
                 console.log("Error")
                 console.log(er);
                }
              });
            }
           } catch (e){
             console.log("Error 2")
             console.log(e);
            }
       });
      })().catch(e => console.log("Error 3" + e));
    }
    }
```

**index.js**

```
app.post('/albums/:id/songs', db.upsertSong)
app.post('/albums/', album.addAlbum)
app.put('/songs/:id', db.upsertSong)
app.post('/albums/:id/upload', image.upsertImage);
app.put('/albums/:id/upload', image.upsertImage);
```

The album info and songs info get inserted on the same save button in React but how does the song know that the album_id is from that album id on the same page?

Comment: The way that the question is worded makes it difficult to understand what's being asked.  There is a page mentioned a few times: what page?  Can code be provided for the page or, alternatively, a picture or other visualization?

Comment: @avejidah okay I added an image

Comment: How are functions `addAlbum` and `upsertSong` invoked?  Are they accessed via an API hit?  If so, do you hit one API that calls both methods, or do you make multiple API hits--one to save the album then one to upsert the songs?

Comment: @avejidah I updated my code. Hopefully that answers your question. I'm using POST in React in all separate functions to save the album data the song data and the image data but they are all used in the same save button function..

Answer (score 0):

The crux of the issue is that the `addAlbum` method is not returning the ID of the newly-created album, so there's no way to associate the songs and images with the album after the album is inserted.  There are multiple ways to solve this, but were it me I would simply update the `addAlbum` method to return the album in its entirety after creation (that is, including the new UUID).  A post might look like this:

```
POST /albums HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "title": "Dillon",
  "date": "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "description": "An awesome political protest album."
}
```

Given the suggestion above, the response would look like so:

```
{
  "title": "Dillon",
  "date": "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "description": "An awesome political protest album.",
  "id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Then, on the front end, your code would look something like this (pseudocode).

```js
const newAlbum = await albumDao.save(album);

for (const song of songs) {
  song.album_id = newAlbum.id;
  await songDao.save(song);
}
```

Another option is to save the album and all of its images and songs together in one orchestrated API.  The advantages of doing it this way are that 1) the server knows about the album ID, and 2) you can utilize transactions so that if a song or image fails to insert, the whole shebang gets rolled back.

Comment: Okay since a little less confused on the second option can you show me what that looks like in a sandbox or something? If not I can try to figure it out on my own.

Comment: Just to reiterate, I would probably go with the first route.  In my mind I think separating out the APIs how you have them is the way to go.  Anyway, with the second method each album would have a structure like so: `{title: string, date: Date, description: string, id: string // uuid, songs: Song[], images: Image[]}`.  Server side, after creating an album you would just iterate over `songs` and `images`, set the `album_id`, and insert.

Comment: Okay I think I would go with the first option then. I would save the id to the album using uuid right but how would I retrieve it and set it for the songs and image album_id?

Comment: What I'm pointing out is that your `/albums` API needs to return the id of the album after it's created.  You need the id of the album to save songs/images to it, so return the id from the API.

Comment: How do I retrieve that id in my songs INSERT or do I retrieve in on the frontend?

Comment: You get the album id on the front end.  That last pseudocode snippet I made is front-end code that saves the album and, when complete, sets the new id on each song.

Comment: so I have to await for the album data to be saved then fetch it and put it in my songs data before I save all the data together?

Comment: How do I get that data from that specific album id? I have to return it on my backend and then how do I retrieve that on my front end?